# Failed to Parse and JAX-RPC 1.1 method is not supported in WLS 8.1 clients error

Tags: eclipse, web-services, wsdl, jdeveloper, oc4j

I got a WSDL and its client from a third party, when i load the client in my jDeveloper its working fine. But when i create a client from that WSDL its giving me "Failed to Parse WSDL" error. And with some modifications in my client i am getting "JAX-RPC 1.1 method is not supported in WLS 8.1 clients. If you are attempting to run an OC4J 10.1.3 JAX-RPC client in WLS, please see the Web Service Migration Guide for instructions". Even I have tried to user their client jar in eclipse and created a class file to call there client but still i am getting "JAX-RPC 1.1 method is not supported in WLS 8.1 clients. If you are attempting to run an OC4J 10.1.3 JAX-RPC client in WLS, please see the Web Service Migration Guide for instructions." same error in eclipse.

Please help !!